# Resettable reminder application for Android

Tags: android, mobile, notification, reminders, timer

I'm a bicyclist who rides on narrow high-pressure tires. Because they are narrow, they pinch flat easily unless they have high pressure. Because the pressure is high, pressure loss over time is also high, so they need to be inflated every two weeks. If I won't do this, I'll have to suffer high rolling resistance and risk having pinch flats.

I'd like to find an Android application that reminds me about inflating the tires with a notification.

The standard Android calendar notifications won't work for this use case. If I create a task with two-week interval, and set it to be done on Monday, it will remind me every other Monday with 2-week interval. However, due to bad weather I won't ride my bike every Monday, so the day on which I inflate the tires might drift.

What I'd like to have is some application that lets me create recurring tasks with 2-week recurrence from the moment when I marked the previous instance of the task done. For example:

- On 10.10.2021 (today), I inflate my tires
- On 24.10.2021 (2 weeks from now), I get a notification about inflating the tires. However, it's raining so I won't be riding the bike this day. I won't mark the task done.
- On 25.10.2021, it's still raining, the notification persists
- On 26.10.2021, it's still raining, the notification persists
- On 27.10.2021, it's still raining, the notification persists
- On 28.10.2021, it's still raining, the notification persists
- On 29.10.2021, it's still raining, the notification persists
- On 30.10.2021, it's still raining, the notification persists
- On 31.10.2021, it's still raining, the notification persists
- On 1.11.2021, it's no longer raining and I'll be riding my bike again. I mark the task done. The application remembers the 2 week interval and sets the notification to happen again
- On 15.11.2021, I again get a notification again about inflating the tires.

So essentially I'd like the notifications to work like a 2-week long countdown timer, with the exception that I don't hear a continuous alarm exactly when the timer ends, but rather get a non-annoying notification with the opportunity to set the countdown timer again. The standard Android countdown timer won't work because it has 99 hour 59 minute 59 second maximum and because when the timer stops, it starts an annoying alarm rather than a non-annoying notification.

Manually setting the next task on Android calendar could work, but is time-consuming because I have to manually put the next instance of the task on the correct date.

Is there an Android application that does what I want with minimum effort?

Comment: Maybe [Simple Calendar](https://www.simplemobiletools.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I found what the feature I'm looking for is called. It's called "flexible recurrence".

One application which supports it is [Todoist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todoist&hl=en&gl=US). Unfortunately, it requires Google account to use, so it probably distributes all your todo items to a central server that uses them for evil marketing purposes but I don't care as there's nothing secret in my tire pumping schedule.

In Todoist you put the keyword "every! 2weeks" in the task name. This keyword means it will recur automatically 2 weeks after you mark it done.